# Is there any source of information about Liam Clancy's song "For Real"

Tags: history

I'm looking for any kind of source of information, regardless of medium, about Liam Clancy's song "For Real", regarding lyrics, background, commentary, etc. I can't seem to find anything about it.

Comment: Welcome to Music Fans! That's gonna be a tough one!

Comment: what sources have you checked ?

Comment: Just scouring google but no useful results about that song in particular. I've also read through most of the wikipedia articles related to Clancy and artists he's associated with but I don't think its mentioned in any of them.

Comment: Well, there is some information on Discogs - the song is from a 1997 release by [Clancy, O'Connell and Clancy](https://www.discogs.com/artist/1271087-Liam-Clancy)
Liam Clancy, Dónal Clancy, Robbie O'Connell are the musicians : they performed as a group from 1996-99. Robbie is Liam's nephew, and Dónal is Liam's son.
Links offering copies of the CD / LP for sale with pictures of the sleeve don't reveal anything more about the song

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The song is from a [1997 release by Clancy, O'Connell and Clancy](https://www.discogs.com/master/1674709-Liam-Clancy-D%C3%B3nal-Clancy-Robbie-OConnell-Clancy-OConnell-Clancy). Liam Clancy, Dónal Clancy, Robbie O'Connell are the musicians : they performed as a group from 1996-99. Robbie is Liam's nephew, and Dónal is Liam's son. Links offering copies of the CD / LP for sale with pictures of the sleeve don't reveal anything more about the song.

After listening to the song and further searching for fragments of the lyrics, I found that the song was written by [Bob Franke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bob_Franke).
Bob (born 1947)  is still living as at the time of this answer. He is a widely respected singer/songwriter, writing songs in the folk style which have been adopted as part of the folk repertoire. [Bob Franke official website](https://bobfranke.com/)

His songs are much covered : extract from [2017 interview](https://meandthee.org/interviews/bob-franke-2017/)

> **This list of musicians who have played your songs is awe-inspiring: Peter, Paul, and Mary, Kathy Mattea, Garnet Rogers, Claudia Schmidt,
> and David Wilcox to name a few. I can only imagine the joy that you
> must feel when you hear someone else singing your song. Are there any
> renditions that are your particular favorites?** They are all
> favorites, as you might expect; June Tabor’s version of “Hard Love”
> showed me things I didn’t know were there, and Lui Collins’ version of
> “For Real” came at just the right time to encourage me.

This [site with the lyrics](http://sniff.numachi.com/pages/tiFORREAL.html) credits the lyrics of "For Real" to

> "Copyright (c) 1983 Telephone Pole Music Publishing (BMI)".

Versions (a selection from many):

[Bob Franke, Fast Folk Musical Magazine (Vol. 2, No. 4) The Boston Area](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pb95qxc1QfE)

[Lui Collins "There's a light"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5PJ-ZsIbxWQ)

[Clancy O'Connell and Clancy:](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q7rjZLUlamc)

Glad you asked the question, I had never heard of Bob Franke before, and was not aware of some of what Liam Clancy had written either......

Comment: Much appreciated! I knew which album Clancy's cover was in but the rest is new info to me.